# How to filter Power Query based off of a range of values in a table?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Ok, so I have a range of values that will change every month and I would like to be able to filter a Power Query off of these but can't quite get the code right. Below is the code I have for pulling the table into Power Query and that works as you can see from the picture below the code. As you can see from that code my table name in Excel is Job and the column I am filtering off of is Order. The second set of code is the code I have to try to filter my query off of this table unsuccessfully thus far. I pasted the entire code for the query but it's really the #"Filtered by Order" line I believe is where the issue is. Any help on getting that code to work would be greatly appreciated.

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Job"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Order", type text}})
in
#"Changed Type"
```

[image]

```
let
Source = Sql.Database("jansql01", "mas500_app"),
dbo_vdvInvoiceLine = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="vdvInvoiceLine"]}[Data],
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(dbo_vdvInvoiceLine,{"Description", "ItemID", "STaxClassID", "ExtAmt", "FreightAmt", "TranID", "TradeDiscAmt", "FormattedGLAcctNo", "Segment1", "Segment2", "Segment3", "SalesOrder", "CustID", "CustName", "TranDate", "PostDate", "City", "StateID", "ItemClassID", "ReleaseSO", "Job Number"}),
#"Filtered by Order" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each Table.Contains(Order,[SalesOrder = [Order]])),
#"Added Material Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered by Order", "Material $", each if [ItemClassID] <> "INSTALLATION" then [ExtAmt] else 0),
#"Added Installation Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Material Column", "Installation $", each if [ItemClassID] = "INSTALLATION" then [ExtAmt] else 0),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Installation Column",{"TranID"},vdvInvoice,{"TranID"},"vdvInvoice",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded vdvInvoice" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "vdvInvoice", {"STaxAmt"}, {"vdvInvoice.STaxAmt"}),
#"Extracted Date" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded vdvInvoice",{{"TranDate", DateTime.Date, type date}, {"PostDate", DateTime.Date, type date}}),
#"Added Invoice+Tax" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Date", "Invoice+Tax", each [TranID]&Number.ToText([vdvInvoice.STaxAmt])),
#"Sorted Invoice+Tax" = Table.Sort(#"Added Invoice+Tax",{{"Invoice+Tax", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Invoice+Tax", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Invoice+Tax2", each if [Index]=0 then [#"Invoice+Tax"] else if #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[#"Invoice+Tax"]=[#"Invoice+Tax"] then null else [#"Invoice+Tax"]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
#"Added Tax Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Tax $", each if [#"Invoice+Tax2"] = null then 0 else [vdvInvoice.STaxAmt]),
#"Changed Tax Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Tax Column",{{"Tax $", type number}}),
#"Added Total Contract" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Tax Type", "Total Contract $", each [#"Material $"]+[FreightAmt]+[#"Installation $"]+[#"Tax $"])
in
#"Added Total Contract"
```

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. It seems that you have two queries and you want to filter the second query to keep only rows where the order number is present in the first query. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I created the first query based off a table in Excel so that query/table will change every month. But yes, I want to keep only the rows where the order number is present in the first query. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Merge the two queries. There are settings in the Merge command that you can click to keep only matching rows.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about merging the queries since I did make the table into its own query, that may work. I'll have to give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I've been crazy busy at work lately and haven't had a chance to test this yet. I'll definitely let you know once I get a chance to. Should be next week.

Comment: @JamieWalker  let me know how you get on. With Power Query, there are situations where you need to shift your paradigm. This scenario is one of these cases. Instead or referring to an external table as a source for a filter, you simply merge the external table with the current table and keep only the rows that fit your criteria. The criteria are defined in the merge options.

Answer (score 0):

teylyn's answer is a good and possible approach.

Another way to approach this, may be passing the Order numbers of the Job table as a list into the filter argument in the second query:

```
Orderlist = Job[Order]
.
.
.
#"Filtered by Order" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each List.Contains(Orderlist,[SalesOrder])),
```